# Highstock column chart y axis ceiling issue

Tags: jquery, highcharts

If the y datapoint is 100, and the `ceiling` is set to `101` the column chart top y-axis label is 150, this is happening in the current version v2.1.4. Before I used to have v2.0.4 and it was showing properly. Now the chart looks compressed. Is it possible to fix it ? All my charts are looking like dwarfs.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b105prjp/)

Comment: That seems like the correct behaviour to me - if the ceiling is 101 and it is displaying in increments of 50, 150 is what I would expect to see at the top.  Why not set the ceiling to 100?

Comment: @BenjaminRay I need some space on top of the chart, so that it doesn't look awkward. This was the behavior in the previous version. The business people got used to that behavior, now if they see the charts are shrunk, they are freaking out

Comment: You could change the ceiling to 100 and add some padding to the top of the div - would that give you the space you need?  Will the values ever exceed 100?

Comment: No, since its percentage, it will max at 100 always. How to add the padding to top of div.

Comment: I've added an answer that gives you a couple of options re: spacing.

Comment: Have you tried to use [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) on yAxis ?

Answer (score 0):

**Chart maximum height issue:**

Change the ceiling to 100, since (according to your comment) the value will never exceed 100.

```
yAxis: {
    floor: 0,
    ceiling: 100,
    title: {
        text: 'Percentage'
    }, // etc...
```

---

**Extra spacing above chart issue:**

*Option 1* ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/5yLmLnz6/)):  If you need the space above the chart title, simply add a margin-top value to the existing container's CSS:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

*Option 2* ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/tfgw7gv4/)):  If you need the space between the chart title and the top of the chart, the best way I've found to accomplish that is to set the chart's title to be blank ('') and add a custom title above the chart itself with a bottom margin applied.  Normally I would suggest overriding the chart's CSS, but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

```
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: '', // This clears the default title
xAxis: // etc...
```

Add a custom title to the HTML:

```
<div id="title" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;">Y axis floor is 0</div>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

PS - Ideally, all of your styles would be in a separate .css file, or at least a `<style>` block in your document. I've used inline styles to give you some quick solutions based on how you are already styling your document.